# How to upload a larger file from a java mobile app?

Tags: java, file-upload, mobile-application

I have done a backup and restore application for java phone including nokia, it works fine but pictures larger than 1 MB cannot be uploaded is that possible to upload a file larger than 1 MB, if so please suggest me whether it is possible on HTTP or FTP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this step by step tutorial. What you need is to send files in multiple parts over a persistent `HTTP` connection.

[**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.**](https://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)